# Display block on certain page

Tags: blocks

I want to display a block on the user/* page. I checked "only the listed pages" and entered "user/*" but the block also appears on "user/*/relationships" for example.

How can I keep the block on just the first path?

Comment: "Just the first path" is which path?  `user/*` is supposed to show all pages such as `user/relationships` `/user/mycustompath` etc., because `*` is a wildcard.  Where exactly do you want to show the block?

Comment: Just on the individual user's profiles, and not on the accompanying tabs associated with it.

Comment: @user12763, you copied my code into your question. This is not irrelevant. Thus, I edited your question to get it back to the original state. I wonder why you did not understand what I said in the code: `&& you may add more conditions here by checking arg(1), arg(2)` which is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you want more control on this, you can choose the option "**Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)**" and you can write the following similar code snippet the the box.

```
<?php
if( arg(0) == 'user' /* && you may add more conditions here by checking arg(1), arg(2) */) {
    return TRUE; // will display the block
}
return FALSE; // will not display the block
?>
```

The alternative way is to check the path with regular expression:

```
<?php
if( preg_match('/^user\/[[:digit:]]$/', current_path()) ) {
    return TRUE; // will display the block
}
return FALSE; // will not display the block
?>
```

This will show your block only at the path **user/***.

Comment: I tried it out and is still displays on user/*/edit i just want it on the user's main profile. nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Check "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only) in block settings" and paste:

```
<?php
if ((arg(0) == 'user') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == NULL)) {
   return TRUE;
}
else {
   return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my answer - `arg(0) == 'user' /* && you may add more conditions here by checking arg(1), arg(2) */` :)