# How to blocks visible only in specific pages?

Tags: 6, blocks

I am setting the links as a block in the left panel with the following code.

```php
function notification_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks[0] = array(
      'info' => t('Notification Management'), 
      'weight' => 0, 
      'status' => 1, 
      'region' => 'left',
      'visibility' => 1,
      'pages' => 'notification'
    );

    return $blocks;
  }
 
  else if ($op == 'save' && $delta == 0) {
    variable_set('notification_block_items', $edit['items']);
  }
  else if ($op == 'view') {
    switch ($delta) {
      case 0:
        // Your module will need to define this function to render the block.
        $block = array(
          'subject' => t('Notification Management'), 
          'content' => notification_block_conent(),
        );
        break;
    }
    return $block;
  }
}
  
function notification_block_content() { 
     $ret = '<a href="'.$base_url.'/notification/addTemplate">Add new email template</a>';
     $ret .= '<br/><a href="'.$base_url.'/notification">Manage Email Notfication</a>';    
     return $ret;
}
``

Unfortunately, this block is appearing in all the pages. I need to display this block on the notification module only. How can I achieve this?
```

Comment: In the block settings you can configure pages, where this block should appears. Is it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the block configuration page and scroll down to  **Page specific visibility settings**.

There are the following options.

> Show block on specific pages:
>
> - Show on every page except the listed pages.
> - Show on only the listed pages.
> - Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only).

If you are using last option from the above options, see [Display block on certain page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60133/display-block-on-certain-page).